# Could I load the Playstation OS on a computer hard drive, and play with a controller?

Tags: pc, ps3, mods

Hypothetically, I was wondering if there was any reason I shouldnt be able to dual boot Windows 7 and the Playstation 3 Operating System on my computer (maybe with the use of 3rd party software), and have a PS3 controller plugged in to my USB port, and play my computer as a playstation? If I were to try to do this, what are some reasons it wouldnt work? I'm thinking that maybe the biggest problem would be the interaction with the hardware that is different than normal/standard PS3 hardware (IE my quad core processor/motherboard to go with it).

What do you guys think? Because a google search didnt work. If this idea doesnt work, short of buying a capture card and console and hooking it up, is there a way to set up a playstation with a computer?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer - no

PS3 has a completely different hardware, different cpu architecture, different everything.
 Theoretically, you could emulate the PS3 hardware, but you would need an insane PC from the future and you'd also have to code the emulator, because no one in their right mind is going to bother with that in the nearest 10+ years. It's the reason why even PS2 emulators require fairly powerful PC, even though the PS2 itself is ancient by today's standards.

Comment: whelp, that answered my question... damn but thanks :)

Comment: You can, however, install Linux on your PS3 and use it as a PC. This site, from Sony's official PlayStation website, explains how: http://www.playstation.com/ps3-openplatform/

Comment: @Kevin Not on a newer model or one that has recent firmware, as Sony got rid of that feature due to people figuring out how to use it to bypass the PS3's software protection.

Comment: Fun fact: Emulating a particular hardware typically requires hardware about 20 time as powerful, or more.

Comment: @GonnaDoStuff If you want to write your own answer, do that, but please don't hijack other answers. Please also stay professional and give details.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for the necro bump, but there is now official software released by Sony called [PlaystationNow](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/explore/psnow/devices/) that allows you, with some guidelines and a subscription, to run PlayStation titles on your PC

Comment: Thats streaming, so the OS is run on server-side and fed to the client which isn't processing anything (effectively), which is why a PC can handle it. This is a VERY different process than the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few technical problems that would prevent this:

1. The PlayStation uses a [Cell processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_(microprocessor)) as its CPU, which is based on the IBM PowerPC architecture.  Windows doesn't run on Cell processors.
2. The PS3 [encrypts the hard drive](http://www.ps3devwiki.com/ps3/HDD_Encryption).  You can't even switch a PS3 hard drive between different PS3s without reformatting it.

Point 1 also makes it harder to emulate the PS3, as a Cell processor has 9 cores (one for the PowerPC chip and 8 for the SPUs).

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure if it will work, but you can try it. As I know PS3 has 2.5 inch SATA notebook hard drive installed inside the console. What you can do is to remove PS3 Hard Drive and insert in your laptop (gaming laptop recommended). Or you can use caddie, from SATA 2.5 to USB adapter, and boot into your pc.